# Common meeting point including velocity of people

Tags: algorithm, math, coordinates, distance

I need to find best location to meet for any X people on given map.
For example

```
A(0, 0) Speed: 1
B(10,0) Speed 100
C(0, 10) speed: 2
```

Answer to such a problem should be somewhere next to (0,3)

It's just finding a place (and time) where all of ABC can meet as soon as posible.

What algorithm do you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Without any directions, this would just be the weighted centroid, with the weight being the inverse of the speed.

So, in your case:

```
x = (0 * 1/1 + 10 * 1/100 + 0 * 1/2) / (1/1 + 1/100 + 1/2) = 0.0667
y = (0 * 1/1 + 0 * 1/100 + 10 * 1/2) / (1/1 + 1/100 + 1/2) = 3.311
```